# Most stable ROS version for running PR2?

Tags: navigation, move-base, pr2, arm-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I started using ROS few months back and have been switching between Fuerte and Groovy lately. I use ROS mainly for interacting with PR2 in simulation.

Many tutorials inside ROS related to PR2 seems to be based on Diamonback or Electric.
Such as .

```
http://www.ros.org/wiki/arm_navigation/Tutorials
```

And most of tutorials in there doesn't work in Fuerte or Groovy.

Which version does people mostly use?
Please share any opinions. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55332/most-stable-ros-version-for-running-pr2?/) by [jys](https://answers.ros.org/users/3404/jys/) on ROS Answers with karma: 212 on 2013-02-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

PR2 simulation in Groovy is still not the most stable.  Would recommend sticking to Fuerte for now.  I use Groovy on the real PR2, which is fine, but switch between Fuerte and Groovy still for simulation.

---

Originally posted by [hsiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/142/hsiao/) with karma: 741 on 2013-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jys](https://answers.ros.org/users/3404/jys/) on 2013-02-17**:
The problem I have is that with Fuerte, I find most tutorials not working. Do you face similar probelms?

**Comment by [hsiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/142/hsiao/) on 2013-02-17**:
which tutorials?

**Comment by [jys](https://answers.ros.org/users/3404/jys/) on 2013-02-17**:
Among many these really don't work on Fuerte and Groovy: [www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_pick_and_place_demos/Tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_pick_and_place_demos/Tutorials)
Do you know of any working pick and place demo?

**Comment by [hsiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/142/hsiao/) on 2013-02-17**:
Hm.  Those are pretty out of date, aren't they?  I just updated the pick and place autonomous demo tutorial:  http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_pick_and_place_demos/Tutorials/The%20Pick%20and%20Place%20Autonomous%20Demo/  for Fuerte.  Let me know if something still doesn't work.

**Comment by [dejanpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/92/dejanpan/) on 2013-02-18**:
You run Groovy on real PR2? That means you guys run Ubuntu 12.04 on your PR2s?

**Comment by [hsiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/142/hsiao/) on 2013-02-18**:
Yup, Groovy/Precise.